# How do I integrate WSO2 Data Analytics Server and WSO2 API Gateway?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-das

I can't seem to get them to communicate even on the same box.
Are there step by step instructions I can follow that I can go through to figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, if you are trying to publish API statistics you can follow https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Publishing+API+Runtime+Statistics

Answer (score 2):

From API Manager 1.10.0 onwards, you can fetch summarised data using two clients:

1. The REST client which fetches data directly from DAS.
2. The RDBMS client which fetches data from RDBMS.

You have have look on [Publishing API Runtime Statistics](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Publishing+API+Runtime+Statistics)